# how can i extern a variable for a namespace in c#?

Tags: c#

i want to declare a global linked list for a namespace in c#. i tried to extern the linked list but do not know the correct syntax. can any one tell me how to extern variables?

Comment: This is C/C++ thinking.  Be sure to learn the language before you consider creating global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the C# syntax for extern is much more limited, or even radically different, from the C++ world.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e59b22c5(v=VS.80).aspx
.

Maybe what you really want to implement is a singleton or a static member of a class?

```
// Note: thread safety not implemented...
namespace Sample
{
    public class GlobalLists
    {
        public static List<SomeObject> SomeGlobalObjects;
    }
}
```

Then you can reference the above list as

> GlobalLists.SomeGlobalObjects

in the rest of the code...

Answer (score 5):

namespace may contain only classes. Static public field of static public class has maximum availibility. Do you need more than it?

Comment: my question is how to extren a linklist how can i do so?

Comment: i do not understand verb "extern". Please give some details.